# 'method ' attribut on from disapearing when I use 'preg_replace()'

Tags: preg-replace

I have some HTML that I cannot change, so I need to use `preg_replace()`.

I get the HTML like this -

```
$form = wp_login_form(array('echo' => false));
$form = preg_replace('/action=".{1,1000}["]/', 'action="'.get_admin_url().'admin-post.php"', $form);

echo $form;
```

If I comment out the `preg_replace()` line, I have this -

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="http://dev.drinkingday.co.uk/wp-login.php" name="loginform">
    {form stuff here}
</form>
```

However if I leave that line in I'm left with this -

```
<form id="loginform" action="http://dev.drinkingday.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-post.php" name="loginform">
    {form stuff here}
</form>
```

Where has the `method` attribute gone? Can anyone please tell me why this has dissappeared? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the original location of the method attribute wasn't after the action attribute and the original location of the name attribute wasn't before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that with this code all your dreams will come true:

```
$form = preg_replace('~\baction="\K[^"]+"~',
                     get_admin_url() . 'admin-post.php"', $form);
```

*As you can read in my comment, I think that if attributes diseapear, it's because you use the dot with a greedy quantifier (i.e. `.{1,1000}`) that catches all characters it can (until the first newline) and then backtracks to find a character followed by a double quote. Thus all attributes after the action attribute will be removed.*

Comment: You could be on to something. In the original script, `method` is output after `action` (the above example was taken from the page source). I've tried your code and it's not quite working though - `<form id="loginform" method="post" admin-post.php"="" wp-admin="" dev.drinkingday.co.uk="" http:="" action="action=" name="loginform">` (with a linebreak inbetween `admin-` and `post.php`). Thanks.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise I see that you had removeed `action="` from the replacement. I removed the last `"` from the regex (and the replacement string!) as it doesn't seem necessary, and it looks to be working like a charm. Thanks for you time and effort.